# How do I add the SWC file for Cairngorm to my app without FlexBuilder?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, cairngorm

I am not using FlexBuilder, I'm using the free Flex SDK with [TextMate](http://macromates.com/). I'm having some trouble figuring out what [this FlexBuilder process](http://nwebb.co.uk/blog/?p=58) actually does behind all the nice dialogs and things, so that I can do the same thing by tweaking whatever the relevant file is, but Googling just points me at similar instructions telling me to use FlexBuilder.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mxmlc` considers a `swc` a library (it's actually a zip file that you can examine) so you'll want to do something like the following:

```
mxmlc -compiler.library-path /path/to/your/swc
```

You can get help with `mxmlc -help <TERM>`. For example:

```
$ mxmlc -help library-path
Adobe Flex Compiler (mxmlc)
Version 3.3.0 build 4852
Copyright (c) 2004-2007 Adobe Systems, Inc. All rights reserved.

-compiler.external-library-path [path-element] [...]
    alias -external-library-path
    list of SWC files or directories to compile against but to omit from
    linking (repeatable)
-compiler.library-path [path-element] [...]
    alias -l
    list of SWC files or directories that contain SWC files (repeatable)
-runtime-shared-library-path [path-element] [rsl-url] [policy-file-url] [rsl-url] [policy-file-url]
    alias -rslp
     (repeatable)
```