# Textmate + Actionscript 3 - Load custom flex compiler config

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I need to load a custom compiler config when compiling my project with textmate (as3 project)
How can i do this?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464659/how-do-i-add-the-swc-file-for-cairngorm-to-my-app-without-flexbuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mxmlc -load-config your-config.xml
```

See also:

- [Using the Flex Compilers](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_01.html)
- [About the application compiler options](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html)